# ECB and multiple similar views

Tags: uml, class-diagram

My teacher told me that in the entity-control-boundary we need to create a boundary class for each view of mock-up but I can't really understand if this is always true.

For example if i have a mock up for a sign up like this [image]

Then is a class diagram like this right? Or it's better create only one boundary class called "SignUp".

[image]

Comment: you are best off asking your teaching but i think you are applying ECB too literally. Enity it the user, Control is arguably signing in, but it doesnt change the user so... and the boundary is the app or page that asks for username/password. you dont assign them to actual classes/interfaces

Comment: @Ewan so the class that I drew it's wrong? I just need to use a single class called "SignUp", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Entity-Control-Boundary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) approach is about breaking down **responsibilities** based on use cases. There is no fixed rules for how many classes for each responsibility. However ECB is driven by the use-case (the business goals of the user) and not by the user interface.

In this regard, your class design looks like an MVC, with a controller driving the views, and not like an ECB with a control coordinating business logic with the assistance of entities and (self-driving) boundaries.

**Some background**

ECB is based on a use-case analysis. For a given use case, you’d have a different boundary for each involved kind of actor. In your case it’s one boundary.

You can break down this responsibility into as few or as many class as suits your needs. You could have one class for the whole boundary, one class per window, or even one class per UI element in the window. Moreover, after the initial break down, boundary classes are generally restructured/refactored to reuse elements that are common to several boundaries, or merge similar classes in a way to get a consistent UI. There is no fixed rule for that.

Since the boundary is the (user) interface with an actor, you’d have one class that managed the dialogue with the user (if it would be a system user, that boundary would be replaced with an API). This class is missing in your diagram.

ECB is not MVC despite the similarities and this is why it’s not really about the views.